20 year old HVAC system., the heat works; refrigerant leaks in the outdoor unit. Can I replace the outdoor unit only at this time?
I have a 20 year old HVAC system. The heat works fine. There are refrigerant leaks in the outdoor unit and it is cost prohibitive to replenish the refridgerent alone, plus the cost to find and fix the leaks.
I would prefer to simply replace the outside unit only, at the present time. Is this a reasonable choice?
Please advise.

AC units are sized with compressor/condenser (outside unit) and Air Handler (inside unit) as married components.
Most every HVAC pro will tell you you need to replace the entire system. They are not totally lying to you, especially with you having a 20 year old system.
That said, I have replaced just the compressor unit in a few rental homes. The trick is knowing what compressor will work with the air handler. I have an advantage of an HVAC pro as a friend who is willing to find me scratch and dent or early take out units that are very good, sometimes new.
You can try contacting AC companies and describing your dilemma. Ask about damaged units or early take outs, ( Units that were installed and then removed shortly after because of owners not liking them or a variety of reasons) Many companies will not bother with these, but others will. You may have to make many calls.
Another possibility is CraigsList (if you have it in your area) Look for HVAC techs that are looking for extra work. Ask if they can look at your unit and tell what compressor you can use.
A final possibility is look into mini-split units. They are super efficient, and often more affordable than new central air or central heat pumps.
